# How to fix validation_data getting passed into input_1 argument in model.fit_generator?

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow, keras

I'm trying write a hybrid model on the functional API with multiple inputs. The problem is when training the model I get the ValueError after one epoch:

```
ValueError: Error when checking input: expected input_1 to have shape (168, 5) but got array with shape (5808, 5)
```

What I'm confused is that is that how did the validation_data (shape (5808,5)) get passed to the input_1 (shape (168,5)) argument in the model.fit_generator ?

I've rollbacked to a sequential model to see and confirm if this problem exists, but it trains just fine.

This is the model fit func:

```
%%time
model.fit_generator(generator=generator,
                    epochs=10,
                    steps_per_epoch=30,
                    validation_data=validation_data,
                    callbacks=callbacks)
```

Its the same as in the sequential data case which works.

The model itself:

```
# first input model
input_1 = Input(shape=((168,5)))
dense_1 = Dense(50)(input_1)

# second input model
input_2 = Input(shape=((168,7)))
lstm_1 = LSTM(units=64, return_sequences=True, input_shape=(None, 7,))(input_2)

# merge input models
merge = concatenate([dense_1, lstm_1])
output = Dense(num_y_signals, activation='sigmoid')(merge)
model = Model(inputs=[input_1, input_2], outputs=output)
# summarize layers
print(model.summary())
```

The model summary:

```
Layer (type)                    Output Shape         Param #     Connected to                     
==================================================================================================
input_1 (InputLayer)            [(None, 168, 5)]     0                                            
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
input_2 (InputLayer)            [(None, 168, 7)]     0                                            
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
dense (Dense)                   (None, 168, 50)      300         input_1[0][0]                    
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
lstm (LSTM)                     (None, 168, 64)      18432       input_2[0][0]                    
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
concatenate (Concatenate)       (None, 168, 114)     0           dense[0][0]                      
                                                                 lstm[0][0]                       
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
dense_1 (Dense)                 (None, 168, 1)       115         concatenate[0][0]                
==================================================================================================
```

The validation data:

```
validation_data = ([np.expand_dims(x_test1_scaled, axis=0),
                    np.expand_dims(x_test2_scaled, axis=0)],
                   np.expand_dims(y_test_scaled, axis=0))
```

Note that I do have to pass the entire test data which has 5808 observations.

data_generator

```
def batch_generator(batch_size, sequence_length):
    """
    Generator function for creating random batches of training-data.
    """

    # Infinite loop.
    while True:
        # Allocate a new array for the batch of input-signals.
        x_shape = (batch_size, sequence_length, num_x_signals)
        x_batch = np.zeros(shape=x_shape, dtype=np.float16)

        # Allocate a new array for the batch of output-signals.
        y_shape = (batch_size, sequence_length, num_y_signals)
        y_batch = np.zeros(shape=y_shape, dtype=np.float16)

        # Fill the batch with random sequences of data.
        for i in range(batch_size):
            # Get a random start-index.
            # This points somewhere into the training-data.
            idx = np.random.randint(num_train - sequence_length)

            # Copy the sequences of data starting at this index.
            x_batch[i] = x_train_scaled[idx:idx+sequence_length]
            y_batch[i] = y_train_scaled[idx:idx+sequence_length]

        x_batch_1 = x_batch[ :, :, 0:5]
        x_batch_2 = x_batch[ :, :, 5:12]
        yield ([x_batch_1, x_batch_2], y_batch)
```

```
batch_size = 32
sequence_length = 24 * 7
generator = batch_generator(batch_size=batch_size,
                            sequence_length=sequence_length)
```

https://github.com/Joichiro666/depo/blob/master/LSTM-DNN%20Problem.ipynb

I expect that the validation_data gets passed to the validation_data argument, not the input_1.

Answer (score 0):

When you are doing a `fit` with some `validation_data`, this validation data will do a forward pass in the network (that's why validation is passed at some point through `input_1`). Therefore it must fit the requirements of your model, in which you specified that the input data must have a shape of `(168, 5)`, which in numpy arrays is going to be `(batch_size, 168, 5)`. I think you may have been confused a bit and added the `batch_size` in the input shape of your network (I can tell not only by your question but also because you are applying a dense layer on a 2D input). In keras you don't need to do that, you should just specify the shape on an instance basis.
I think if you do that you won't have to expand the dimensions of your inputs anymore.

Comment: 'm sorry but I don't quite follow. As I've posted above the input shape is indeed (168,5). I need the dense layer (MLP concatenated with LSTM) and I'm not sure what you mean by specify the shape on an instance basis.

Comment: Can you describe your data with words? For example how many samples do you have in your training set? What are the input parameters? Like I said, I think since you are applying a dense layer on your input, the input shape is probably 1D.

Comment: I have 34896 samples for the training set.  x_train_scaled, y_train_scaled are my inputs to a data_generator and their shape is (34896, 12), and (34896, 1) resp. My inputs to the model from the data_generator are [x_batch_1, x_batch_2], y_batch whose shapes are (5808, 5), (5808, 7), and (5808, 1) resp. 5808 is the number of samples of the test set.

Comment: Ok so your input dimension for `input_1` is `(5,)`. When you specify the input shape in keras, you don't need to specify the batch size, you just specify a single smaple's shape.
The batch size is specified afterwards.

Comment: I changed the input shape for both into (5, ), and (7, ) for input_1 and input_2 respectively. However an error occurs: "Input 0 of layer lstm is incompatible with the layer: expected ndim=3, found ndim=2". Is a tf.expand_dims the way to go?
Specifically: input_2 = tf.expand_dims(input_2, axis=-1)

Comment: have you also changed the input shape in the LSTM definition?

Comment: I did, and the error is this: "Input 0 of layer lstm is incompatible with the layer: expected ndim=3, found ndim=2. Full shape received: [None, 7]"

Comment: Ok but an LSTM is supposed to have one time dimension and one feature dimension, while the Dense layer is supposed to only have a feature dimension in input. Maybe you want a TimeDistributed Dense layer? Could you describe your data so that we know what exactly you are trying to do?